# How can I catch undefined behaviour when re-using moved data?

Tags: c++, move, compiler-warnings, static-analysis, undefined-behavior

The following code exhibits undefined behaviour:

```
#include <memory>

void consumer(std::string && str){}

int main(){

  std::string str = "foo";
  consumer(std::move(str));
  str = "bar"; //<- UB
}
```

How can I catch this?  There doesn't appear to be any compiler warnings in `gcc` or `clang`.

I also tried using the undefined behaviour sanitizer:

```
clang++-3.9 -std=c++1z -g -Weverything -fsanitize=undefined  -o main main.cpp
```

It did not catch anything.
Are there reliable ways to catch these problems?

Comment: Why UB? Re-assigning a moved-from object a new value is a well-defined behavior.

Comment: What makes you believe this code exhibits undefined behavior? Looks fine to me.

Comment: I see. I misunderstood, and thought it was UB.

Comment: Note that you don't even have a moved from object here. Your function doesn't consume anything at all. The "valid but unspecified state" does not apply. The state of `str` is both valid and well-specified.`str == "foo"` before and after the call to `consumer`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Why doesn't the function consume?  Because its not using the parameter in the body?

Comment: @TrevorHickey: Well, it depends upon what you mean by consume. I assumed you meant that the object was moved. It wasn't. Moving happens when the move constructor or move assignment operator is called. You didn't do that anywhere, you just passed  the object by reference to a function, and didn't modify it in any way.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I got the "consume" terminology from the C++ guidelines:  http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#a-namerf-consumeaf18-for-consume-parameters-pass-by-x-and-stdmove-the-parameter